# How to calculate change in volume of a container using rainfall data

Tags: precipitation, rainfall

I have 2 data. A container data, 3 containers(A1,A2 and A3) all are the same height, but each have varying water volume, the table consist of change of water volume (hourly) for the weeks 1 and 2.

[image]

.. ..
Precipitation and rainfall intensity data (mm/hr), the range is weeks 3 and 4.

[image: Precipitation Data]

..
I want to show(predict?) what will be the change of volume in the containers for weeks 3 and 4 due to precipitation. My goal is to present it using graphs or any other method applicable.

Comment: Are you saying A1, A2, and A3 are rain gauges at different locations?  Because for A1 to go down from t=.75 to t=1 while A2 and A3 go up suggests that must be.  As such, predicting the values of all three from only a single rainfall dataset would seem quite tough?  If this is homework, maybe your teacher wants you to determine the regression equation for each one... otherwise I'm not sure your description helps us to understand the situation well enough.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest No, A1, A2 and A3 are not rain gauges, they're just containers on different sites. The rainfall data are coming from the internet. This is an experiment to show how the precipitation data will affect the volume in each containers. I wanted to know the connection or what will be the relation between the two datasets.

Comment: But one dropping while the other two increase suggests they aren't reasonable for collecting rain?